# "expression must have integral type" switch problem in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm new in C and I would like to know how can I correct this error I can keep getting please: 
"expression must have integral type"

```
switch (detect_format(format))
{
case "%d":
    printf("teqs");
    break;

default:
    break;
}
```

note : `detect_format(format)` returns a string.

Comment: Re: *note : `detect_format(format)` returns a string.* That would be a string **pointer**, which is unlikely to be the same as the pointer to the string literal `"%d"` even if `switch` could work with pointer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the standard, `C11`, chapter 6.8.4.2:

> *The controlling expression of a `switch` statement shall have integer type*

A *string* is not allowed.

That said, the case labels, also need to be integer constant expression, something like `case "%d":` is also illegal.

If you want to take a decision based on the returned *string*, you will need to use `strcmp()` and use the result as the controlling expression of a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You **Can't** use switch-case with `%d` like you did in your code: (`case "%d"`).
What you have to do is to use it with integers like:

`case 1:
    //code//
    break;
case 2:
    //code//
    break;
//and so on...`

there are **smarter** solutions but since you're new to C Programming, you can use simple integers to adjust your specific cases.